# Getting Last Available element of a Particular Column in JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have been working on a Bash script. I am having a curl response as follows.

```
{
  "range": "'PR-DETAILS'!A1:Z1000",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "PR ID",
      "PR Owner"
    ],
    [
      "1929",
      "Angel"
    ],
    [
      "73",    
      "Martin"
    ],
    [
      "142"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**Here I just want to get the last available element for the second column.**

Expected Answer:- `Martin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
last(.values[] | select(has(1))) [1]
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/l8LHozbdgSS)</sup>

If the second column does not contain false values (`null`, `false`) this will also work:

```
last(.values[][1] // empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different solution:

```
.values | map(.[1] | select(.)) | last
```

probably less efficient, but quite readable.

The difference to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73616835/112968) is that `select(.)` will filter any falsy value, not only non-existent values. So if your second columns were to contain `false` or `null`, these wouldn't show up in your result.

Comment: As of the nature of `select(.)`, this disregards values present but equal to `false` or `null`.